# What parameter should my pop function take?

Tags: c++, templates, stack

Here's my function,

```
    template <class KeyType >
    KeyType * Stack<KeyType>::Pop(KeyType& x) {
        if (IsEmpty()) {  //isempty is just a bool function
            StackEmpty(); //just prints out that stack is empty
            return 0;     //bad coding breaking out of the function
        }
        x = stack[top--]; //stack is a pointer to an array, top is the top of the stack
        return &x;
    }
```

My questions is:
I'm not sure how this would be called in main.  To my understanding a pop function shouldn't really have an option of what to pop off of the stack. LIFO right?  The main question is what exactly does the Keytype& x parameters take and how would you call it in main? (in this case the KeyType is initialized as KeyType *stack an int in this particular program).

Comment: Actually the Stack's Pop method should not accept any parameters as it will always return the top most element in the stack, since it is a Last In First Out data structure.
I think that your Pop method will return a pointer to the Stack top element as well as the value itself; the first as the return value, and the later is passed by reference.

Comment: its not actually a stack, it's an implementation of a stack using a class, probably should have put that somewhere in there but this was in a header file an instructor gave us so I'm assuming it's viable.  I've been debating whether to just delete the parameters for awhile lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a *very weirdly* designed function.

`Stack` is a class template parameterised by the type stored on the stack (named `KeyType` for some reason). The function takes an **output parameter** `x` of type reference to `KeyType` and if the stack is not empty, assigns the popped value into `x`. At the same time, it returns its address (it returns a pointer to `KeyType`). If the stack was empty when `pop()` was called, it will call `StackEmpty()` and then return a null pointer.

Usage:

```
int main() {
  Stack<int> stack;
  //fill stack somehow
  int val;
  stack.pop(val);  //val will be set to the popped item, or unchanged if the stack was empty

  // You can also use the return value to access the popped item:
  std::cout << *stack.pop(val);

  // ... or use it to test whether the pop() succeeeded
  if (stack.pop(val)) {
    //val was popped, use it
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation sir, yeah i wouldn't have set it up like that at all it was just a part of a basic stack template our instructor gave us to use for a homework assignment where we have to make other functions and I couldn't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

It fills the value of the popped item

```
int main(..)
{

   ...
   int poppedItem;

  stack.pop(poppedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `KeyType` parameter is an `int` as you said, then your `Stack` will probably look like this:

```
Stack<int> stack;
```

The ampersand in the `Pop` method means that you pass in a *reference* of the `KeyType` (which is `int` in your case). That is, the `Pop` method does not only return the value of the popped item but also puts the value in the passed argument.

```
int a, b;
a = *(stack.pop(b));
cout << a << " = " << b << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

variable x is the same that return value (just other way to get top element that was excluded from stack)

```
Stack<int> my_stack;

// blah-blah-blah ...

int tmp;
int* tmp_pointer = my_stack.pop(tmp);
some_func(tmp);
some_other_func(*tmp_pointer);

// tmp_pointer == &tmp;  
// you can use one of two ways
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding the function takes any element of keytype and retrieves a reference.

so calling

```
int value = 0; 
Pop(value);
```

is calling Pop with &value - so in fact with the address of the int value and therefore by reference.

I wonder about the `return 0` in case you called Pop with any non numerical datatype the compiler might tell you, that the return statement is invalid. Maybe returning NULL would be better. (At least better to read)